# How we can install aws lambda extesnsion to access aws lambda from postgres trigger if we are running postgres on docker container?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am working on one use case where I have to trigger lambda to send email if some event occurs, here event is postgresql trigger that will be attached to one table. AWS provide AWS lambda extension with AWS RDS for easy connection to Lambda. But in my case I am running postgresql in docker container, do we have any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done the following steps during the process of integration of AWS Lambda with PostgreSQL:

1. Create an IAM role with required permissions for the Lambda function.
2. Create a Lambda function to handle email sending.
3. As AWS Lambda Extension for RDS won't work in Docker, create a custom Lambda extension using AWS SDK or CLI.
4. Install the custom Lambda extension in the PostgreSQL Docker container.
5. Create a postgreSQL trigger on the table to invoke the Lambda function.
6. Trigger the event to test the Lambda function.

Hope this will help you out :)

Comment: Alright, I understood. But how to create a custom Lambda extension using AWS SDK or CLI?